# Support Google Maps for both Froyo and above. Google Play Services v4030500 issue

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I have an app in the store which `minSdkVersion=8`. Recently I've tried to upload a newer version of the app and it failed with message stating that Google Play Services have been upgraded to `version=4030500` and it has dropped support for Froyo, which means that the `minSdkVersion` now ha to be `= 9`.

I definitely want to support Froyo devices. How can I deploy the app for both Froyo API and those which above it? Does it have to do with gradle flavors, separate apk files for Froyo and the rest?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to support Froyo?  According to Google, less than .7% of all devices downloading apps run Froyo.  That's a LOT of work to support .7% of the market and dropping.  Gingerbread is at 13% and dropping fast (it was 16% a few months ago), but I can see supporting that.  There's no economic sense to Froyo.

Comment: Why shouldn't I? I still see a bunch of people with froyo using the app and until now I had no problems with the GoogleMap from the services package.

Comment: Because its going to be a LOT of work to support a very few people.  If its a money making app, the opportunity costs are high-  there's almost certainly better things you can do to get more users and make more money.  If you're doing it without money as a goal then do what you want-  but there's a lot more interesting things to be doing with that amount of time.  Its like writing support for Windows 98-  there's still a few people using it, but it really isn't worth the time.

Comment: Add new googleplayservice library, inclde metatag for lib version , and add support library in lib, change mapview with SupportMapFragment.

Comment: Also, as time goes on fewer and fewer libraries will support Froyo and more features will be impossible to use on it.  There comes a time to cut support to obsolete versions.